# tkFileDialog.askdirecotry loop until 'cancel' - tkinter python

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm trying to run a loop that makes you choose a directory, then upload files from that directory. I cant get the loop to stop neatly (without errors) when you press 'cancel'

```
def search_audit():
    chosen_dir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir=os.sep, title='please select a dir')
    return chosen_dir

def splunk_uploader(ip, port):
    #code to connect socket
    chosen_dir = search_audit()
    while chose_dir != 'NULL': #This won't work
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(chosen_dir):
            for filename in files:
                c = os.path.join(path, filename)
                f = open(c, 'r')
                while True:
                    #code sends file
                    s.send(line) #line errno points to, works fine first directory chosen
        chosen_dir = search_audit()
s.close()
```

What I was hoping is for the program to run and ask for a directory until I pressed cancel. It keeps asking for a direcotry and runs, but when I press cancel, it uploads entire C: drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value against `None` rather than `'NULL'`.  As your code is written now, it will only stop of they choose a file literally named `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Also works with #while chosen_dir != ''